# Flash Development Server 4.5 Advice

Tags: directory, flash-media-server

I have just downloaded Flash Media Development Server 4.5 on Windows. This was not an upgrade from 3.5 or 4.0 for example. My problem is when i go to start>Programs>Flash Media 4.5>Start Flash Media Server for some reason i am unable to login but when i go in my web browser i type in localhost URL i can login. Why is this? Furthermore, I am unable to see my applications folder or config in my documents.

Have i missed something here? Did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The Start Flash Media Server in the start menu has no interface, it simply tells FMS to start.
The login screen is part of the Administration console which is only accessible through the swf/web browser.

Your applications and config folder are by default not found in documents, but in the install directory of FMS,  probably  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 4.5\ for most people.